# Should I accept an earlier date to be interviewed?

Tags: interviewing

I am a developer and have a job interview for the next week. I picked last date of the week. But today I am contacted to be interviewed on Monday instead. I have been told there is already one candidate for each of remaining days. They can not take more than one candidate on the same day.

The problem is that the technology I will be interviewed about is new to me (and to the other candidates too, they said). So if I do the interview on Monday, I have fewer days to get prepared, and this is clearly disadvantageous for me and a candidate with more days of preparation may have more chance than me (only one of us will be chosen for the job)

Can I ask for an interview on the following week instead of accepting this Monday? Or do you think if I do so they will think: "See, this candidate can not work under stress and learn quickier"

Comment: Why are you applying for a job that you don't have the skills for? And why are you trying to hide the fact that you don't know this technology? You presumably wouldn't be honest with the interviewer about your reason for wanting more time? Or have they actually told you that they're checking how fast you can study up on this topic?  Why are you assuming that none of the other candidates would know the technology? This question is rather confusing to me.

Comment: @Lilienthal: I never started a job where I knew all of the *technology* - does not mean I did not have the *skills* to master it. Why would one work somewhere where there is nothing new to learn?

Comment: @Daniel The new tech is a framework, I master its programming language and I already understand a good part of its logic.

Comment: If a new technology can be learned in a few days, it's a piece of garbage.

Comment: The technology is an ERP, so far from being garbage :) @scaaahu

Comment: What I mean is that you can't learn it in a few days if it's a good new technology.

Comment: @virtualbox: Did they say this Interview was specifically about the framework in question, and that you should prepare for that? If you already stated that you don´t know the specific framework, and are able to talk about it´s internal logic already on the second interview I´d see that as a plus already. Now if they specifically asked you to have a second meeting and have the framework prepared, my answer would probably change...

Comment: @Daniel They asked to prepare to be tested for a set of things that I all know already. About the framework, they asked to only read about its ORM and the test will involve programming in this ORM (and other things I know already)

Comment: We had only one round for the moment in which they selected few of us to go to the second round. For the second round, I am supposed to be familiar with the ORM of the framework (only that ORM). Other things they asked are already familiar to me because they do not belong to the framework specifically @Daniel

Comment: Ok so this is for you to decide: If you feel you need more time to prepare what they asked you for, delay. If you feel comfortable with the ORM part. use your advantage to interview first.

Comment: "*The technology is an ERP, so far from being garbage*" Well that's debatable. But my point isn't that you shouldn't ever go for positions you might not be 100% (or even 70%) qualified for but rather that you should be honest with yourself and with the potential employer that you don't have a particular skill. What are you going to do if intricate knowledge of this framework is a key job requirement? Do you want to be fired for performance reasons (or deceit!) a few weeks after starting the job?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I understand what you mean but in the first round of the interview, I clearly informed the company I have never heard about this ERP before. This is the case of all other candidates. @Lilienthal

Comment: @virtualbox In that case, why are you trying to learn all you can about it? You've been honest with your lack of knowledge, all that's expected of you is to maybe google around the name of the ERP to get some broad info on it and even that isn't really a hard requirement. You're drastically overestimating your required prep time I think. Have a look at the similar questions on that topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask, and being unavailable at a certain day is normally not a problem. I would not state your reason though, just that this Monday does not work for you as you already have other appointments.

I´d think about taking the early date anyways, as I think this gives you an advantage. Employers try to limit their investment. If they have a strong candidate on before you, chances are that you won´t have an opportunity anymore. If you interview first, you are the first one to make an impression, so use it!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Do you think they will take in consideration the fact I have fewer days to get prepared than other candidates, if I accept Monday?

Comment: @virtualbox I don't believe anybody expects you to learn a technology just for a job interview. It should be possible for you to prepare over the weekend. If you need more preparation, you don't appear to be qualified for the job.

Comment: That is an encouragement for me, thank you very much @Roland